# Using loop to perform actionPerformed( on click button)

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to implement this actionPerformed method on my calculator program. I'm having trouble creating a loop which will display the buttons and performs calculation when pressed. By the way, I can fix my problem if I do this by one using if statements but I want to make my code cleaner. 
     Here's my code:

```
     String expr1 = "";

         private static final String[] bText = {"7", "8", "9", "+", "4", "5", "6", "- ", "1", "2", "3", "*", "0", ".", "=", "/", "(", ")", "C", "CE"};
         Button[] buttons = new Button[ bText.length ];

         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent arg0 ) {

         String input = textField.getText();

         // Trying to get the first 12 items for testing 
         for( int index = 0; index <=12; index++)
         {
             if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[index])
             {

                 if(input.contains("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0"))
                 {
                 textField.setText(input + bText[index]);
                 expr1 = expr1 + index;
                 }
                if(input.contains("+-*/")){
                     expr1 = expr1 + bText[index];
              textField.setText("");
                 }
             }

         }    
            for( int i=13; i <=16; i++){
              if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[i]){
             expr1 = expr1 + bText[i];
              textField.setText("");

            }
          }
         /**
           If I do this one by one using if statements I can fix my problem but I want to make my code cleaner. 

          */


          //For CE button
          if (arg0.getSource() == buttons[18]) {
             String s = textField.getText().toString();
             s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
             textField.setText(s);

          }
                else if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[17]) {
                textField.setText("");
                expr1 = "";    
            } 
         // This will calculate expressins. This is a "=" button 
         else if (arg0.getSource() == buttons[19]) {
               System.out.println(expr1);
                textField.setText("" + Integer.toString(calculatorEvaluator.eval(expr1)));
            }


      }
```

Comment: Please format your code so it's more readable and better explain your problem. What trouble are you having and why does the `if` help?

Comment: You can access to the button from the event by using `JButton btn = (JButton)arg0.getSource();` from this you should either use `getText` or `getActionCommand` to determine the action to be performed

Comment: I was wondering how I can minimize the length of code by using for loop. If I do by using if statements I have to use 20 if statements, and I was wondering if there is a shorter way. i.e ; loop. Sorry for formatting, I'll do it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm actually doing that. If you scroll down to the end, you can see my if statements. I was able to access the button from the event. I want to use a loop instead of if statements.

Comment: @user7062312 You're not ... really, kind of...The basic idea is, you have two types of button, a number (let's excluding `.` for the moment) and a operator. You could set the `actionCommand` to, say `number` or `operator`, your first job would be to determine what "type" of button you have, from there you can make the required determinations, in a short number of statements, of how to handle.  The looping is a performance drag which can complete in a better way - just saying ;)

Comment: @user7062312 And `String#contains` doesn't work that way ;)

Comment: @user7062312 A much better solution would be to use `Action`s, where you would have a "number" action and "operator" action and some other "modification" action (to reset/clear), I think `.` might be a special case ;). Basically you would have a model which represented the current "value" and current "input". The model would then allow you to apply a given operator to the model and the model would take the current input and apply it to the current value and update the current value ... but now I'm just thinking out loud ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you, I will try your way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways I can think of approaching this problem, using the `Action`s API is probably my most preferred, but may be beyond the scope of the requirement here.

I don't think you need to use loops, I don't think they are going to give you any advantage over other approaches.

For example, you could make use of `String`s built in regular expression support and simply check the text of the button.

This would, at least, allow you to determine if the text is a number or an operator or some other command, for example...

```
private final String[] bText = {"7", "8", "9", "+", "4", "5", "6", "-", "1", "2", "3", "*", "0", ".", "=", "/", "(", ")", "C", "CE"};
private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[bText.length];

public TestPane() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));
    for (int index = 0; index < bText.length; index++) {
        String text = bText[index];
        JButton btn = new JButton(text);
        buttons[index] = btn;
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        add(btn);
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source instanceof JButton) {
        JButton btn = (JButton)source;
        String text = btn.getText();
        if (text.matches("^[0-9]")) {
            System.out.println(text + " is a number");
        } else if (text.matches("^[=/\\(\\)*=\\-\\+]")) {
            System.out.println(text + " is an operator");
        } else {
            System.out.println(text + " is some other command");
        }
    }
}
```